# DSE Hive taking a constant time of 30 seconds for aggregate functions like sum() and count(*). Map and Reduce Jobs taking too much time

Tags: cassandra, hive, delay

Recently i configured dse on my system for a project. Now i want to use hive to fetch data from cassandra. Everything was fine. It just took below 1 second for select * queries. But the problem is it is taking a constant time of around 30 second for queries that using aggregate functions (I mean whenever map reduce job is launched). I edited mapred-site.xml(also dse-mapred-default.xml :D) based on datastax documentation to tune up hive performance. But unfortunately no change. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Hive is not meant for faster query processing. Its a data warehouse system which is preferred when you want to process huge amount of data in batch.

If you need faster results I suggest you try hbase/cassandra.

Comment: I am using Cassandra. But in report generation i want to use some aggregate functions that are not available in Cassandra

Comment: ok, but the queries on hive have high latency no matter how small the data is. Real power of hive lies in batch processing huge amount of data.

Comment: Anyway...Thanks sunil I decided to use Apache Spark(provided within dse4.6). It is faster. Thanks for your reply anyway.